# Reemplazo de la función xp_cmdshell en SQLServer para Linux

Tags: sql, linux

tal vez alguien pueda ayudarme. Tengo una aplicación en C# en la que entre otras cosas envía órdenes al SQLServer para generar, hacer copias de seguridad y restaurar bases de datos, etc. Ciertas órdenes como crear la carpeta donde se guardará la copia de seguridad, eliminar carpetas, etc. se hacen a través de la instrucción SQL xp_cmdshell, esto funciona correctamente para el entorno Windows, el problema es que necesito hacer esto mismo pero para un servidor remoto con Ubuntu y SQLServer para Linux (versión 2017) en el cual no está disponible la función xp_cmdshell , mi pregunta es ¿cómo reemplazar esta función en SQL Server para Linux por otra que me permita interactuar con el sistema operativo Linux para crear y eliminar directorios?

He estado averiguando como usar el agente de trabajos sql pero aún no he tenido buenos resultados, y no sé si la solución puede venir por ese lado o debería usar SQLCMD, SSIS o Powershell, son opciones que leí en la web pero no sé si realmente valen la pena investigar, también intenté generar un procedimiento almacenado para ejecutar en modo SQLCMD:

```
                USE [mibase]
                GO
                SET ANSI_NULLS ON
                GO
                SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
                GO
                CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SQLCMD_CREARCARPETA]
                AS
                !!MKDIR "c:\NewFolder"
```

Pero con esto tengo 2 problemas:

1.cuando desde mi programa C# llamo al procedimiento almacenado "CREARCARPETA" como establezco que digo que  tiene que ejecutarse en modo SQLCMD y

2.Cuando guardo el procedimiento, almaceno los comandos con "!!" no son guardardos, es decir la linea '!! MKDIR "c:\NewFolder"' no se guarda

Comment: En el contexto de un SP los `!!` no significan nada, estos son para el modo sqlcmd del enterprise management. Lamentablemente, al menos hasta dónde conozco,  sobre linux no hay nada sencillo que se pueda hacer para ejecutar comandos del SO en el servidor (lo cual en realidad es una mla práctica).

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Patricio!, hoy estuve probando hacer procedimientos almacenados que la hagan hacer la tarea de crear la carpeta al agente de SQL, en Windows todo perfecto, ahora para Linux, pasa lo mismo, el comando CMDEXEC que lo utilizo para ejecutar las sentencias en el sistema operativo tampoco funciona en la version de Linux. Debido a esto cambie el enfoque y estoy probando no pasar por el SQL, sino conectarme directamente al servidor remoto via SSH y ahi mandarle sentencias tipo RunCommand, hay un nuget SSH.Net (por Renci) que parece que funciona bien